# Why is mathjax not available here?

Tags: discussion

I'm just curious...

Many SE sites use [mathjax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) which allows the users to typeset nice formulas.

I saw (and wrote) some answers with several formulas, which would look better with mathjax, but I agree that mathjax isn't really needed here. The formulas are usually simple and it works as it is. (Also, people would need to learn the syntax of mathjax)

I guess it's just an option or a plugin for an SE site. So why do some sites use mathjax, while others do not? Is there any drawback?

Comment: I think MathJax makes text go crazy if you include a $ sign because it then reads everything after that as notation. I had that problem on the Economics site. I think it's easy to work around it - e.g. by making $$ the sign that what follows is to be treated as MathJax - but the purists always insist on using only $ leaving regular users confused every time they try to say something like "$5 plug"

Comment: @user568458: $$...$$ is used for formulas which are displayed alone in a single, centered line. For inline formulas (within a sentence), $....$ would be the standard, but due to that problem, many SE sites use \$...\$ instead.

Comment: @sweber ... do we really have a need for it here? How often do mathematical formulas actually get written here?

Comment: @Paulster2: No, I don't think so. My question is just more technical: Is there any technical reason why we don't have it, or is it more "we don't need it - we don't activate it"

Comment: I think your latter. If you have seen it on other SE sites, then they could have it here. It's like embedded videos. They haven't seen a need to have it on our site, so they don't have it activated. Amazing we can embed them on the chat.