# Meta reputation

Tags: discussion

When people upvote a meta question do you get reputation for it.

I asked that question earlier and saw an upvote but don't see any record of additional reputation.  Perhaps I'm not looking hard enough.

Does our overall reputation increase with meta upvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't receive any reputation in Meta for up/down voting. In fact the purpose of voting in Meta is unlike its purpose on the main site. Here it really denotes agreement or disagreement with an idea.

For instance, if you post something where you are asking, "Should this be considered on topic?" and you see a bunch of down votes on it. This doesn't mean your question is a bad one (like you'd think it would be on the main site). It would mean *Meta users believe this question is off topic*. If they voted it up, it would mean they think it is on-topic.

Another for-instance:

There is a question on Meta here which is by sweber about [the site using MathJax](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/why-is-mathjax-not-available-here). I downvoted the question, not because it's a bad question, but that I don't agree with the premise of using MathJax on the main site.

When someone downvotes on the main site you can look at this as "what did I do wrong" or "what should I really be asking" ... here on Meta, a downvote is not really a negative about the question, but about the idea in general. It just shows disagreement with the idea, as I've stated before. Here the upvote is a confirmation vote of the question and the idea.

This is the way it was explained to me in another forum when my Meta question started receiving downvotes and I got pissy about it. It makes sense to me as well, so there you go :D Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes total sense.  I've wondered about this so many times in the last year and again, didn't even look on meta.  Makes complete sense to me.